# Give required field for show/hide textbox when selected from the dropdwon

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have to give the show/hide textbox required field.. When user selects Others from the dropdown textbox will be shown.. I have to give required field for that textbox.. Here is the code

```js
$("[name='mass']").change(function(){ 
    
    if($(this).val() == "Other" )
    {
        
        $('.other').slideDown();
        $('.other').slideDown().find('.other').attr('required', true);
    }
    else
    {
         $('.other').slideUp();
        $('.other').slideDown().find('.other').attr('required', false);
    }
     });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="mass" id="types" class="col-md-12" required="required">
     <option value="">Mass</option>
     <option value="Soul of">Soul of</option>

        <option value="Other">Others</option>
  </select>

<div class="other" style="display:none;" >
 <label style="text-align:center;">If Others</label>
     <input type="text"  name="other" id="other" placeholder="If Others"  maxlength="30" class="col-md-12"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `.find('.other')` you are looking for a class but the input is having `id="other"` not `class="other"`

Also in your `else` statement you are sliding using `slideUp` and `slideDown` so it will always be show.

```js
$("[name='mass']").change(function() {
  if ($(this).val() == "Other") {
    $('.other').slideDown().find('#other').attr('required', true);
  } else {
    $('.other').slideUp().find('#other').attr('required', false);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="mass" id="types" class="col-md-12" required="required">
  <option value="">Mass</option>
  <option value="Soul of">Soul of</option>

  <option value="Other">Others</option>
</select>

<div class="other" style="display:none;">
  <label style="text-align:center;">If Others</label>
  <input type="text" name="other" id="other" placeholder="If Others" maxlength="30" class="col-md-12"></div>
```

Comment: Isn't this a typo type question in that case?

Comment: @ChrisG well it's a mix, the id part is, but the slide up and down in the else I believe is not. Also this will give the op a better understanding of that he dont need 2 x slidedown statements